# How to pass a Linked list as a function parameter in java

Tags: java

I am struggling in "How to pass a Linked list as a function parameter" in java. 
This method is supposed to take another linked list as a parameter, and add the contents of this linked list to the calling instance's linked list. Adding the elements should only be done if the element does not already exist. All elements to be added should be added at the end of the linked list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us the code that's giving you trouble.

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem?  That you don't know how to declare a method with a linked list as a parameter, or are you having problems implementing the logic you have described?  You need to be more clear about what *specific* problem(s) you are having.  One of the best ways to do that is to share the code you have so far (like musical_coder already mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

In Java every parameter which is not of primitive type (int, long, byte, char, boolean...) is passed as a reference to that object.

Here's a simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   List<?> myList = new ArrayList<>();
   myList.add(1);
   myList.add("Sarah");
   process(myList);
   Iterator it = myList.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(it.next());
   }
}

public static void process(List<?> list){
 list.add("Johnny");
}
```

The output will be:

```
1
Sarah
Johnny
```

Meaning the list you passed as parameter is actually passed by reference hence "Johnny" gets added.

This applies to any real object (extends Object).